# чтение писем с mail.ru

Tags: python, mail.ru

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть задача чтения писем mail.ru и переход по вложенным ссылкам, подскажите, как такое реализовать с помощью почтовых библиотек, а то вариант с Selenium webdriver очень медленный.

Нашел такой вариант, но не совсем понимаю как его правильно применить

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
mail.login('login', 'pass')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest

# fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") 

raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email
# including headers and alternate payloads
```

Comment: Тут код сам говорит за себя. Все что вам в итоге нужно будет дописать, это обработку полученных данных. Читайте комментарии между строками

Comment: с помощью import base64 мне выдает такое b'J\xe6\xe3y\xcb', но это совсем не тот результат который Я ожидал

Comment: зачем вам `import base64`? Вы получаете от кода выше все что нужно, айди, результат и текст.. Если тут есть `base64`, то выполните что-то вроде следующие `base64.b64decode(raw_email).decode('utf-8')`